# NullPointerException :

Tags: selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea, nullpointerexception, pageobjects

I wanted to try and implement Page Object Model in my code. The first page would be responsible for opening url, and giving username and password.
Currently my code opens the url and loads the webpage without locating the element, then opens a new blank window and repeats this three or four times.
Crashes while trying to locate element. Can anyone tell me where I am making mistake. I have stored below details in Config .I am checking code again and again but not able to find issue

```
public class Base {
               public static WebDriver driver;
               public static Properties prop;
            public Base(){
                    try {
                        prop = new Properties();
                        FileInputStream ip = new FileInputStream("C:\\config\\config.properties");
                        prop.load(ip);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            
                }
            
                public static void initilization()
                {
                 String browsername = prop.getProperty("browser");
                 if (browsername.equals("chrome")){
                     
                     System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\chromedriver.exe");
                     driver= new ChromeDriver();
                }
                  driver.manage().window().maximize();
                  driver.get(prop.getProperty("url"));
                  driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(70));
                  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(70));
                 
                }
            
            }
```

Login page :

```
      public class LoginPage extends Base {
        @FindBy(name = "username")
        WebElement username;
    
        @FindBy(name = "password")
        WebElement password;
    
        @FindBy(xpath = "//input[@type='submit']")
        WebElement loginbutton;
    
        @FindBy(xpath = "//button[contains(text(),'Sign Up')]")
        WebElement SignUpButton;
    
        @FindBy(xpath= "//img[contains(@class='img-responsive')]")
        WebElement crmlogo;
    
        public void LoginPage()
    {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver,this);
    }
    
    public boolean logo()
    {
        return crmlogo.isDisplayed();
    }
    
    public String validatetitleofpage()
    {
        return driver.getTitle();
    
    }
    public HomePage login(String un,String psd)
    {
        username.sendKeys(un);
        password.sendKeys(psd);
        loginbutton.click();
        return new HomePage();
    }
    
    }
```

This is LoginTest from where I am calling all methods :

```
        public class LoginPageTest extends Base {
        LoginPage LoginPage;
        HomePage HomePage;
        
            public LoginPageTest()
            { super();
            }
         @BeforeMethod
            public void setup()
            {
                initilization();
                LoginPage = new LoginPage();
            }
        
            @Test (priority = 1)
            public void loginPageTitleTest()
            {
                String title = LoginPage.validatetitleofpage();
                Assert.assertEquals(title,"title details");
            }
        
            @Test (priority = 2)
            public void logoTest()
            {
                boolean logotrue=LoginPage.logo();
                Assert.assertTrue(logotrue);
            }
        
            @Test(priority = 3)
            public void logintest()
            {
                HomePage= LoginPage.login(prop.getProperty("unme"),prop.getProperty("pwd"));
            }
        
            @AfterMethod
            public void teardown()
            {
                driver.quit();
        
            }
        }
```

Below is the error

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
   at com.crm.qa.pages.LoginPage.logo(LoginPage.java:31 undefined)
   at com.crm.qa.Testcases.LoginPageTest.logoTe0st(LoginPageTest.java:37 undefined)
   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at 
                java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
   at `enter code 
          here`java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566 undefined)
                at`org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod`(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
   at `org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod`(TestInvoker.java:598 undefined)
   at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod
                (TestInvoker.java:173)
   at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence
            (MethodRunner.java:46)
   at 
 `org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke`(TestInvoker.java:824)
   at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:146 undefined)
```

Config file

```
    url = https://classic.crmpro.com/
    unme = abcd
    pwd =  Abcd
    browser = chrome**
```

Comment: Based on the exception the exception occurred in the method for checking if the logo is displayed.You may need to check if the `crmlogo` is not null when `isDisplayed()` is accessed. Try to check as well if your locators are correct.

Comment: Thank you @lorvindc for your reply ! While running code,3 instances of chrome are getting open and third instance tries to open the site and then crashes. I feel I am making some mistake while initializing drivers ,but not sure where .

Comment: I have refered https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/43041/how-to-debug-nullpointerexception-in-selenium-java and  https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/44447/java-lang-nullpointerexception-on-my-pom-project-i-have-my-page-factories-initi , after making changes from (browserName.equals("chrome")) to browserName.contains("chrome"),it didnt help.

Comment: After removing below method,browser stays on the page,but cant find element and gives exception for elements stored in config proprties.Method  @AfterMethod
            public void teardown()
            {
                driver.quit();
        
            }

Comment: After removing driver.quit(),browser stays on the page,but cant find element and gives exception for elements stored in config properties. Method which is for verifying title is getting passed,methods for passing username and password not able to find and logo as well. I have changed to Xpath but no luck.Is it like ,config.properties are not getting read properly,if yes,then how come its taking application path correctly..I am trying many things ,but still not able to find the issue.

Comment: Finally could resolve this problem.By mistake void was added for constructor  public LoginPage() ,where I had initialized variables.